# auto.arima in R; exclude consideration of seasonal effect?

Tags: r, arima

I'm very new to the `auto.arima` function in R, but it's recently given me a result that doesn't make much sense with my data. I'm using a seasonally-adjusted series, and while it's true that there might still be some lingering seasonal effect (it's unrevised, for example, but that's what I'm going for), I really should not need a seasonal ARIMA model. However, `auto.arima` gives me a seasonal `Q` component equal to 1; not even a seasonal difference, which is confusing.

Is there a way to exclude consideration of seasonal components within the `auto.arima` function? Obviously I could just fit the model manually without it, but I want to be sure that this doesn't materially change the result.

Answer (score 4):

Putting `??auto.arima` in the console generates the function documentation (very helpful).

> Returns best ARIMA model according to either AIC, AICc or BIC value. The function conducts a search over possible model within the order constraints provided.

```
auto.arima(y, d=NA, D=NA, max.p=5, max.q=5,
     max.P=2, max.Q=2, max.order=5, max.d=2, max.D=1, 
     start.p=2, start.q=2, start.P=1, start.Q=1, 
     stationary=FALSE, seasonal=TRUE,
     ic=c("aicc", "aic", "bic"), stepwise=TRUE, trace=FALSE,
     approximation=(length(x)>100 | frequency(x)>12), 
     truncate=NULL, xreg=NULL,
     test=c("kpss","adf","pp"), seasonal.test=c("ocsb","ch"),
     allowdrift=TRUE, allowmean=TRUE, lambda=NULL, biasadj=FALSE,
     parallel=FALSE, num.cores=2, x=y, ...)
```

Have you tried setting `seasonal` to `FALSE`?